# EACCESS error when installing packages on WSL

Tags: npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I'm getting this error trying to NPM INSTALL packages on WSL from VS Code.

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/cssstyle' -> '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/.cssstyle.DELETE'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/cssstyle' -> '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/.cssstyle.DELETE'] {     
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/cssstyle' -> '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/.cssstyle.DELETE'] {        
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!     path: '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/cssstyle',
npm ERR!     dest: '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/.cssstyle.DELETE'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/cssstyle' -> '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/.cssstyle.DELETE'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/cssstyle',
npm ERR!   dest: '/mnt/d/DEVRepo/PWS/functions/node_modules/.cssstyle.DELETE',
npm ERR!   parent: 'functions'
npm ERR! }
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The problem is that VSCode WSL extension locks files and that generates the error.

The solution is to close the WSL connection on VSCode o just close the whole IDE and run the npm install command again.

Comment: Are there any other possibilities? I don't have VS code running at all.

Comment: I was still on version 1 of WSL. After upgrading to WSL 2 everything worked fine. I ran this from powershell: `wsl --set-version <distribution name> <versionNumber>` i.e. `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2`

Comment: I get this error but don't have VS Code open.

Comment: removing node modules

Comment: See my answer below for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74455303/1461862

Comment: You are a genenius! You save my life I waste almost three days trying fix a problem with AWS cdk which already has a lot of problems with permissions! It was just that! TKS 

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading to WSL2 from WSL1 helped me fix the issue.

To check the version of WSL run this command in powershell.

```
wsl -l -v
```

To set version to 2

```
wsl --set-version <distro name> 2
```

Comment: I had to go back to wsl1 because wsl2 is so much slower :(

Comment: Also don't know about you guys, but WSL 2 for some reason prevents me from interacting with the remote (private) repo - can't push/pull/fetch.

Answer (score 3):

you can fix that error by allowing unsafe perms

```
npm config set unsafe-perm=true
npm install
```

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/14#issuecomment-207504657

Comment: This seems.. unsafe. Is it?

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: keep in mind that `unsafe-perm=true` is the same as doing the install with `sudo`. [see the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#unsafe-perm)

Answer (score 3):

To solve this I had to do the following

- Close vsCode and any other app that is accessing the worskspace folder
- Remove the `node_module` folder (not just the contents)
- from WSL

  ```
  $sudo chown <yourUser> package-lock.json
  $rmdir node_modules
  ```

Finally run `$npm install` from WSL (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error/issue when running

```
npm install -g elm-format
```

WSL version was Ubuntu 2
Cache was fine.
Closed VSCode.
SAME ERROR!

What worked for me was using SUDO in front i.e.

```
sudo npm install -g elm-format
```

Answer (score 0):

- Donwload "package-version.vsix" online
- rename "package-version.vsix" to "package-version.zip"
- create directory /home/user/.vscode-server/extensions/package-version
- extract the contents of to "package-version.zip"
- move contents of "extension" folder of the extracted zip archive to /home/user/.vscode-server/extensions/package-version
- connect to wsl, now it will be installed

Answer (score 0):

Finally find way to upgrade npm by mixing multiple answer :

- Run powershell then change version of wsl distribution

```
# List available distribution
PS C:\Users\CallMarl> wsl.exe -l
Debian (par défaut)
# set version to 2
PS C:\Users\CallMarl> wsl.exe --set-version Debian 2
```

- Run wsl then install lastest-version

```
PS C:\Users\CallMarl> wsl.exe -d Debian
callmarl@LAPTOP ~ % sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

- Then check npm version

```
callmarl@LAPTOP ~ % npm -v
7.20.3
```

- For some reason you can rollback to WSL 1 by running in powershell `wsl.exe --set-version Debian 1`

Answer (score 0):

Since wsl doesn't allow write operation on /usr/lib/node_modules without sudo, we can remap the location where node_modules are installed using below commands.

```
mkdir ~/.npm-new
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-new'
export PATH=~/.npm-new/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile
```

https://cmatskas.com/resolve-npm-access-denied-errors/

Answer (score 0):

In my case node modules was the problem, so I deleted it and ran npm install

every other npm install works

Answer (score 0):

My issue seemed to be WSL having issues renaming the node_modules directory

I tried everything but the only thing that fixed it for me was the following:

- Make sure Ubuntu is running (just have the Ubuntu CLI open)

- Open windows file-explorer
- Type \\wsl$ into the search-bar in explorer and open the Ubuntu-directory (your Ubuntu directory will not be displayed in explorer unless you have Ubuntu up and running somewhere in the background)
- Navigate to your project via explorer
- Delete node_modules manually (shift + delete)
- Close everything (VScode, Ubuntu, any CLI connected to WSL)
- Open Ubuntu again and navigate to your project (cd projectName) and type "code ." to open an instance of your project in VScode
- Open a new terminal instance inside VScode and type "npm install"

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the File Watcher setting, I installed the extension I needed and then changed the setting back to the default value as it can degrade performance.

Go to File > Settings and search for "Polling" and tick the checkbox. The config is called: "Remote.WSL > File Watcher: Polling"

Or you can change it from the settings.json file:

> In WSL (WSL1), there is a limitation where it is not possible to
> rename a non-empty folder from VS Code. To work around this issue, you
> can tell VS Code to “poll” for file system changes rather than apply a
> lock to the folder.
>
> In your user settings.json, add:
>
> ```
> "remote.WSL.fileWatcher.polling": true
> ```
>
> Polling is resource heavy, so it is not turned on by default. You can
> also tune how often VS Code polls using the
> remote.WSL.fileWatcher.pollingInterval setting, which is by default
> every 5 seconds.
>
> You will need to reload VS Code (Developer: Reload Window from the
> Command Palette (F1)) for these settings to take effect.

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tips-and-tricks-for-linux-development-with-wsl-and-visual-studio-code/#workaround-for-renaming-folders

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its showing this error because you are not the owner of that folder you're working on, for example when you copy a project folder from your windows file system to WSL folders structure. You need to set the owner of current directory to the user you're logged in with, like this:

```
sudo chown <user-name> .
```

Then you can work with the files on that folder

Comment: Doesn't work. Running as `sudo` also results in the same.

Answer (score -2):

Check folder permissions if you have 777 example: chmod -R 777 myfolder

Comment: While this may work for some people it generally shouldn't be necessary and isn't recommended, for me this didn't work, even though it the error reports permissions I believe it isn't to do with that, for me upgrading from WSL 1 to WSL 2 fixed the issue.

Comment: start with **chwon -R \`whoami\` [folder]** instead of jumping strait to trip 7s